# How to control the set of exposed API(s) in a static library?

Tags: c, build, static-libraries

I have a static library which exposes 100 API(s) (i.e. the 100 API(s) are listed in the various header files which I provide along with the library).

Let's say, many different applications try to use this library and each one uses a only a subset of those 100 API(s). For Ex: Application-1 uses 10 API(s) , Application-2 uses 20 API(s) etc

In this scenario, I want only 10 API(s) to be exposed to Application-1 and only 20 API(s) to be exposed to Application-2 i.e. I don't want all the API(s) to be exposed to all the customers.

One of the solution is that, I add a macro based on Application Name and then tailor it out my self in the code.

What are the other solutions available? In case of shared library, I can control the set of API(s) exposed using a map file. Any such solutions can be applied to a static library?

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers have ways of controlling symbol visibility (i.e. whether the symbol is exposed to the linker or not). Here's an article on how to do it in GCC:

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

You should be able to easily find corresponding documentation for other compilers.

In portable code this is often handled using a per-compiler macro.

Comment: I had come across this before. But, this doesn't help for static libraries as I understand. Pls clarify if my understanding is wrong. Thanks.